# Using json schema from another repo

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, schema

We have a common repo where all different projects share their common contract as json schemas. These schemas may be modified from time to time. How do I  reference these schemas from inside my visual studio project without manually including their copies in my project?

Is it possible to wrap these schemas in a nuget package and include them?

Comment: Are they hosted somewhere (ie github)?

Comment: They are in our corporate git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your JSON:

```
"$schema": "https://web.site/schema.json"
```

Obviously, change the URL. If your schema is on GitHub, open the file on the web in viewing mode, then click the "Raw" button.

Comment: The schema is in our corporate git. Solution gets deployed on client's premises. They wont have access to our git.

Comment: @AIKDO this does nothing to the client. It just tells your IDE what schema the JSON uses.